# Magento CatalogInventory QTY Field

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, catalog, inventory

I'm trying to disable the *Qty* field on the product edit tab.

I've created a local Mage override of:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Simple.php` on line 140 (original):

```
/* Inventory Data */
    $fieldset->addField('simple_product_inventory_qty', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
        'name'  => 'stock_data[qty]',
        'class' => 'validate-number',
        'required' => true,
        'value'  => 0
    ));
```

And changed it to:

```
/* Inventory Data */
    $fieldset->addField('simple_product_inventory_qty', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
        'name'  => 'stock_data[qty]',
        'disabled' => true,
        'value'  => 0
    ));
```

I've flushed the cache & still no difference. I've even tried editing the core file itself for testing purposes, and even that makes no difference, even if I completely remove the whole field set addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qty field comes from the template file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml`

```
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><label for="inventory_qty"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty') ?><span class="required">*</span></label></td>
        <td class="value">
            <?php if (!$_readonly):?>
            <input type="hidden" id="original_inventory_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][original_inventory_qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('qty')*1 ?>"/>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-number" id="inventory_qty" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldSuffix() ?>[stock_data][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getFieldValue('qty')*1 ?>" <?php echo $_readonly;?>/>
        </td>
        <td class="value scope-label"><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]') ?></td>
    </tr>
```

You can [change your admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) and add your own template

Comment: Spot on - thanks for the theme advice too.